# MVVM Light WeakAction<TMessage> instances still in memory after view model cleanup

Tags: memory-leaks, mvvm-light

I'm new to MVVM Light and I think I'm experiencing an unexpected behaviour.

Using a memory profiler I noticed that after calling Cleanup on a view model, which extends ViewModelBase and is registered as a recipient for multiple message types, all WeakAction instances are still in memory.

I see that ViewModelBase.Cleanup() should completely unregister the view model as a message recipient, but I also see that Messenger.Unregister(object recipient) does not call RequestCleanup(), while all the other Unregister overloads do.
Explicitly calling the RequestCleanup method in my view model's Cleanup override seems to solve the problem, as all WeakAction instances are almost immediately released from memory.

Can someone please tell me if this is the expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: I cannot find `RequestCleanup()` method in MvvmLights Messenger. Do you use DevExpress Messenger?